# AjaxSetup never execute the success function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a simple registration page that validates if a user is already taken.

I use ajaxSetup for all my ajax calls and for some reason the "success" is never called. When I look at my console (firebug) I can see a successfully request (code 200 OK and I get true or false as the result).

Here's my code:

```
$('#checkValidUsername').click(function() {
    // some basic validation like not empty etc...
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/checkuser.php',
        cache: false,
        data: $("#form").serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            // do some actions
        },
    });
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function() {
        // show loading dialog // works
    },
    complete: function(xhr, stat) {
        // hide dialog // works
    }
    success: function(result,status,xhr) {
        // not showing the alert
        alert('success');
    }
});
```

What is wrong with my code?
Thank you

Comment: Just to add some clarification to the answers already posted, the ajaxSetup method sets defaults. If you supply a success method to an individual ajax request, it will override the default.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

because you are already using `success` in your `$.ajax` call

```
$('#checkValidUsername').click(function() {
    // some basic validation like not empty etc...
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/checkuser.php',
        cache: false,
        data: $("#form").serialize(),
        dataType: 'json'
/*
        success: function(result) {
            // do some actions
        },
*/
    });
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function() {
        // show loading dialog // works
    },
    complete: function(xhr, stat) {
        // hide dialog // works
    }
    success: function(result,status,xhr) {
        // not showing the alert
        alert('success');
    }
});
```

everything in `$.ajax` will override the `$.ajaxSetup`.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the `success` handler inside `$.ajax()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#checkValidUsername').click(function() {
    // some basic validation like not empty etc...
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/checkuser.php',
        cache: false,
        data: $("#form").serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            myAjaxSetup.success.apply(this, arguments);
            // do some actions
        },
    });
}

var myAjaxSetup = {
    beforeSend: function() {
        // show loading dialog // works
    },
    complete: function(xhr, stat) {
        // hide dialog // works
    }
    success: function(result,status,xhr) {
        // not showing the alert
        alert('success');
    }
};
$.ajaxSetup(myAjaxSetup);
```

each object function that you overwrite simply

```
myAjaxSetup.success.apply(this, arguments);
```

or

```
myAjaxSetup.error.apply(this, arguments);
```

or

```
myAjaxSetup.anyfunctionyouwant.apply(this, arguments);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are overriding it when you specify the success function in your ajax call. Try removing that and see if it calls the one from ajaxSetup.

Answer (score 2):

`$.ajaxSetup()` is a means of providing pre-made, default settings that apply to all your future `ajax()` calls unless you override them in that specific `ajax()` call.  When you define a success handler in both the `ajaxSetup()` call and also in the `ajax()` call itself, only one of those success handlers will get called.

So, if you want the success handler to get called from `ajaxSetup()`, then don't define one in the `ajax()` call.  If you define one in the `ajax()` call, then the one from `ajaxSetup()` won't get called.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Global Ajax Event Handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/)

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
  $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxSuccess handler." );
});
```